# How to subset a dataframe in R with multiple conditions?

Tags: r, dplyr, filtering, subset

Need to find the average fertility in Russia after 2004 year in preinstalled dataset gapminder.

```
library(dplyr)
library(dslabs)

df1 <- data.frame(gapminder)


a <- df1@year >= 2004
df1[df1$fertility %in% c("Russia", a), ]
```

This code returns NAs only. I tried different variations and watched few lectures, but could not figure it out, would appreciate your help.

Comment: i'm guessing you mean `a <- df1$year >= 2004; df1[df1$country %in% "Russia" & a, ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the column using `$` (and not `@`), also `'Russia'` is present in `country` column but you are checking in `fertility`.

Try :

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  filter(country == 'Russia', year >= 2004) %>%
  summarise(avg_fertility = mean(fertility, na.rm = TRUE))

#  avg_fertility
#1      1.493333
```

Without using `filter`

```
df1 %>%
  summarise(avg_fertility = mean(fertility[country == 'Russia' & 
                                           year >= 2004], na.rm = TRUE))
```

and in base R :

```
mean(subset(df1, country == 'Russia' & year >= 2004)$fertility, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I couldnt find that precise instruction anywhere and struggled for hours by myself